# HERE map Error: missing license key

Tags: android, sdk, key, licensing

I'm trying to do the simple BasicMapActivity + CompositeMapFragment tutorial from HERE, but no matter what I do, it doesn't recognize the license key.

The package name is the same as the one I registered on their website, also tried with putting the activity's name in the package on their website too (which I find very very ridiculous), but that didn't solve it either. I added the 3 required meta-data parts: appid, appcode, license key. Still no success. Any other tips?

**BasicMapActivity.java**

```
package hu.appz4.heretest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARController;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARController.Error;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARIconObject;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.ARObject;
import com.here.android.mpa.ar.CompositeFragment;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BasicMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="hu.appz4.heretest"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <!-- Additional permission for LiveSight -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"
            android:value="the appid i copied from here site"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"
            android:value="the appcode i copied from here site"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key"
            android:value="the license key i copied from here site"/>
```

[You can see on this image that the package name is correct on the site too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BFDO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving the `<meta-data/>` tags UNDER the `<activity/>` tags.